# OWIN MVC5 with AAD RedirectUri not being redirected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-active-directory, owin

Using OOTB MVC5 with AAD template without any modification.

What I want to do is add additional custom claims after AAD's authentication back to my application.  The ConfigureAuth:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44336/Account/Signin",
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri
            });
    }
```

In the Azure portal, the Reply URLs for the App is entered as above as well.  The actual behavior of the app is that after the AAD login, the redirect just back to the app's root /, and does not hit the Signin action on the Account controller.

Any ideas why?  Something I missed?

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you also have a web.config or appsettings.json where the reply url/redirecturi is set? If so, ensure that it matches there as well.
2. Are you working only locally or is this a published app? Make sure that you have the published app URL included in the app registration and config as well. Also make sure that these are all https and not http (seems obvious but easy to miss).
3. Ensure that your homepage URL is listed correctly.
4. It's hard to diagnose this without seeing your Accounts Controller. Can you please provide this here?

Please check out [this repository](https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect) if you haven't already. It describes in detail how to accomplish what you are trying to achieve.

Also check out this [Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MohaxN6fsDs).